# struts1 in view jsp and struuts2 in Action Controller

Tags: struts2, struts-1

I am working in migrating from struts1 to struts2. its very big application hence it is not possible to migrate entirely. can we use struts1 in UI and struts2 in Action Contoller. Would this combination work ?

Comment: I think you could use struts1 plugin to reuse server side code https://struts.apache.org/plugins/struts-1/, but the UI should change   in any case.

Comment: No, and it wouldn’t be the best approach even if it did. Better to have a hybrid S1/S2 app and convert a page at a time.

Comment: Thanks PKey  Dave Newton for your reply